# Conda Virtual Environment / Plotly Issue in Atom.ide

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, atom-editor, python-venv

I'm trying to build a dashboard app via Plotly.Dash.
Therefore, I'm transitioning from using Jupyter to Atom.ide.

It seems I have managed to set up a **virtual environment** and activated it with no errors; in that virtual environment ***dash_reqlibs.yml*** i'm trying to install **Plotly lib**, which also loads with no errors according to terminal:
[image: activated venv installing lib]

After the installation i'm trying to run my simple test code and it tells me it doesn't see module **plotly**:
[image: running python file with test code]

Now, please note, that according to my research I'm not even supposed to do that since in my ***dash_reqlibs.yml*** I have specified all need - doesn't work either way though:

[image: venv set up]

**UPDATE:**

- Removed bad venv
- Created new one successfully
- Changed to app.py directory and activated the venv
- cannot select venv as it doesnt show up

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you activate your environment before trying to run your code? The error is telling you that plotly doesn't exist. So if you installed it in the anaconda environemnt, you have to activate that environment before running your code. You can check if any of the libraries exist by typing print(numpy.__version__) for example

Comment: @AdamSchroeder Yes, it is activated already - and that's what makes me so confused...
As you can see from my description there is (dash_reqlibs.yml) before my C:/... path, which means I'm in the virtual environment. Also, if you check (screeenshots) I run my app.py after the instalation and in venv as well.

Comment: Your installation is wrong. Your activate environment can't be dash_reqlibs.yml. The .yml file is something you use to create the environment, not to activate it. Try to do it over again itih the instructions I will provide below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating environment from the beginning again, using these steps:

1. Create “dash_reqlibs.yml” file with required libraries
2. Save it inside your Environments folder (or whatever name you call that folder)
3. Open Windows Command Prompt (or Atom terminal) and ‘cd’ into your Environments folder
4. Crate new virtual environment by typing: conda env create -f dash_reqlibs.yml
5. Activate your new environment:
   a.  On Windows, type: conda activate env_dash (name value inside the .yml file)

Let me know how it goes.